# Get percentages of a column based off of another column but with different categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage, series

I have the following Pandas Series:

```
                    Count
Pclass  Survived    
1       0            80
        1           136
2       0            97
        1            87
3       0           372
        1           119
```

But I want something like this:

```
                    Count   Percentage
Pclass  Survived       
1       0           80      37.0
        1           136     63.0
2       0           97      52.7
        1           87      47.3
3       0           372     75.8
        1           119     24.2
```

I want to calculate the percentages based on only the counts in each 
category of Pclass (not the whole sum of counts). It would be great if these
percentages are calculated using only the Count column.

So far, what I did was I summed up the counts according to Pclass and used .repeat() to duplicate the values and tried to concatenate it to the original Series, which failed spectacularly.

```
        Count
Pclass  
1       216
1       216
2       184
2       184
3       491
3       491
```

My idea was to use this repeat column as the denominators in calculating the percentages, like this:

```
80 / 216 * 100 = 37.0%
```

and then remove the repeat column after the percentages are calculated. Seems so simple but I can't seem to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `div` and `sum` with `level=0`

```
df.assign(Pct=df.div(df.sum(level=0), level=0).round(2) * 100)

                 Count   Pct
Pclass Survived             
1      0            80  37.0
       1           136  63.0
2      0            97  53.0
       1            87  47.0
3      0           372  76.0
       1           119  24.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`, divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html), multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) and if necessary [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
#if input is Series create one column DataFrame
df = s.to_frame('Count')

s = df.groupby('Pclass')['Count'].transform('sum')
#if use oldier pandas version
#s = df.groupby(level='Pclass')['Count'].transform('sum')

df['Percentage'] = df['Count'].div(s).mul(100).round()
print (df)
                 Count  Percentage
Pclass Survived                   
1      0            80        37.0
       1           136        63.0
2      0            97        53.0
       1            87        47.0
3      0           372        76.0
       1           119        24.0
```

EDIT:

> dont you have to forward fill on PClass ?

It is not necessary, because default in MultiIndex are not shown, but if set `multi_sparse` to `False` is possible verify repeating values:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
                 Count
Pclass Survived       
1      0            80
1      1           136
2      0            97
2      1            87
3      0           372
3      1           119
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, dont you have to forward fill on `PClass`?

Comment: @VishnuKunchur - No, because MultiIndex

Answer (score 0):

You are working on titanic dataset. You can also do like below on the original data (not on your Series above):

```
df.Survived.groupby(df.Pclass).value_counts(normalize=True)*100
```

It will give you count of each class in percentage rather than in actual number.

Comment: Thank you, this also works. But how would you make it into the format that I requested above, with the two columns Count and Percentage?

Comment: Its just another way to get percentage, not in the exact format as you desired. Answer from @jezrael above is more than great.